# The type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

It is giving me an error when I try to parse my double value.
Price is a String which I am trying to parse into a double but when I try to do that, it gives me an error. I don't know why I am getting this error since double.parse would turn the price into a double.

```
      price: double.parse(
        element.get('price'),
      ),
```

**The error is**
Unhandled Exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`double.parse` or `int.parse` need to parse `String`s. Your error is because the value that is being passed is not a String, but infact a double.

Change this in your code:

```
price: double.parse(element.get('price').toString()),
```

That should work. You can also enhance it by using `tryParse`:

```
price: double.tryParse(element.get('price').toString()) ?? 0,
```

This is in case double.parse fails, and returns a null, your class\function will throw an exception. But using `tryParse` will try to parse it, and accepts nulls, but if this does return null, you are handling it by assigning it a value of 0.